# How to swap the column values in a table with a single update query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with columns

```
ID  NAME    GENDER
------------------ 
1   xxxxxxx m
2   yyyyyyy f
2   zzzzzzz f
```

Now, I want 'f' to be updated as 'm' and 'm' to be updated as 'f' with a single update query.

Kindly anyone help me out

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with a case statement:

```
update tablename t
    set gender = (case when gender = 'm' then 'f'
                       when gender = 'f' then 'm'
                       else gender
                  end);
```

Comment: @juergend . . . I didn't mean "table" as a keyword, just the table name.  `t` is an alias for it (admittedly unnecessary in this case).

Answer (score 5):

For mysql,

```
update tablename 
set gender = if(gender = 'm','f',if(gender = 'f','m',null))
```